# Spacetime as an algebraic surface over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, riemannian-geometry, schemes, general-relativity

First of all I would like to say that I know little about physics so I am very likely to talk nonsense in what follows.

If I am not wrong, spacetime can be defined as a $4$-dimensional differentiable manifold $X$ together with a pseudo-Riemannian metric. Hence, one can study the curvature of $X$, geodesics on $X$, the singularities of the metric, etc.  Moreover, all these concepts have a physical interpretation.

On the other hand, a $2$-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-scheme with some extra hypothesis induces a complex analytic space that gives rise to a $4$-dimensional variety over $\mathbb{R}$.

Taking this into account, it could make sense to define spacetime as a complex algebraic surface $Y$ with some good properties and one could study the most common aspects of this type of surfaces - namely, the singularities of $Y$, some Čech cohomology groups of $Y$, the holomorphic Euler characteristic of $Y$, the self-intersection of the canonical class of $Y$ (if defined), etc. Hopefully, these concepts could also have a physical interpretation.

Maybe there is an obvious reason for this not to be worth studied, but I have not been able to find any information about it on the internet. So, my questions are:

- Could considering spacetime as an algebraic surface over $\mathbb{C}$ be of any help?
- Has someone considered spacetime as an algebraic surface over $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problems is that "*spacetimes*", as understood by physicists, are differentiable manifolds equipped with a "*causal structure*"; see [Techinques of differential topology in relativity](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9707012). It's pretty difficult to see how to define a *pseudo-Riemannian* structure over a scheme. That's the main obstruction to complete your program.

The best that can be done is probably by means of [twistor theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.02196). Twistor theory defines spacetime notions in terms of projective geometry over $\mathbb{CP}^{3}$. Using twistor variables one can understand many spacetime objects such as classical field theory by means of Cech cohomology on twistor space (see [Cohomology of massless fields](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-78/issue-3/Cohomology-and-massless-fields/cmp/1103908690.full)).

The problem is that twistor spaces are very restrictive; they can only be defined for spacetimes with very simple topologies (and asymptotic properties) or by studying the [deformation theory](https://inspirehep.net/literature/114824) of known twistor spaces as analytic manifolds.